# Will 'Erase SD card' fully format it?

Tags: sd-card

My Android 4.2 phone only has an option *Erase SD card* under *System Settings*, but not an option to format.

My card has read errors on some files I want to fully format it to check if it's just a case of logical disk errors (those would go away) or if it's hardware and I should replace it.

I *did* try this (what's to lose?) and it said *Checking SD card* and was done in a few seconds; that's what makes me ask the question.

Would plugging it into my Windows computer and formatting it there be better? Or running `chkdsk`?

I know that there is not really an old-fashioned formatting going on on SSD devices, but I want all card logical sectors to be scanned (read) for errors. Will 'erase' do that?

Answer (score -1):

Erasing the SD Card will format it. If you doubt it, then it would be better to use a card reader and format it via PC.

Comment: *but I want all card logical sectors to be scanned (read) for errors. Will 'erase' do that?*

Comment: Refer this to do that https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/sd-card-sector-reading @JanDoggen